# How to fix "else if" block inside function?

Tags: javascript

Depends on checked input my function payment should display a salary with using `cost.innerHTML`.

But I have problem. My block "else if" is not working.

```
<div class="form__propertyInputs">
        <span>qwerty</span> <input type="radio" name="propInput" id="property" checked>
        <span>Nonqwerty</span> <input type="radio" name="propInput" id="noneProperty">
      </div>

      <div class="form__ownershipInputs hide">
        <span>physical</span><input type="radio" name="ownerShipInput" id="physical">
        <span>judical</span><input type="radio" name="ownerShipInput" id="judical">
      </div>

      <div class="form__debt" id="debtBlock">
        <span>Debt:</span>
        <input type="text" id="debt">
      </div>

      <div class="form__result">
        <span>Sum:</span>
        <div class="form__result-input"></div>
      </div>
```

```
const debtBlock = document.querySelector('#debtBlock')
const debt = document.querySelector('#debt')
const ownershipInputs = document.querySelector('.form__ownershipInputs')
const property = document.querySelector('#property')
const noneProperty = document.querySelector('#noneProperty')
const cost = document.querySelector('.form__result-input')
const physical = document.querySelector('#physical')
const judical = document.querySelector('#judical')
let minSalary = 6700


noneProperty.addEventListener('change', toggleData)
property.addEventListener('change', toggleData)
debt.addEventListener('input', payment)


function toggleData() {
  ownershipInputs.classList.toggle('hide')
  debtBlock.classList.toggle('hide')
  cost.innerHTML = ""
  debt.value = ""
}

function payment() {
  if (property.checked) {
    if ((debt.value * 0.02) <= (minSalary * 10)) {
      cost.innerHTML = (debt.value * 0.02).toFixed(2) + " грн"
    } else if ((debt.value * 0.02) > (minSalary * 10)) {
      cost.innerHTML = (minSalary * 10) + " грн"
    }
  } else if (noneProperty.checked) {
    if (physical.checked) {
      cost.innerHTML = minSalary + " грн"
    } else if (judical.checked) {
      cost.innerHTML = minSalary * 2 + " грн"
    }
  }
}
```

Debugger didn`t help. Give me advise how to manage this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time provide all **HTML markup** for the question.

What I can se in this code why your `else if` block in your code is not working because it is missing a `debt.addEventListener('input', payment)` for the `judical` radio button. The payment function should be called whenever the value of the debt input or the selection of the `judical` radio button changes.

Add this code to make the `else if` block work:

```
judical.addEventListener('change', payment)
```